# Cloned SharePoint Environment on Test Server - Pages Appear in Document Libraries but SharePoint Says They are Deleted

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have created a test SharePoint server to be as close to our production server as possible. Production SharePoint databases were backed up and restored to our test server. The three main web.configs (Central Admin, main site, Security Token Service Application) were modified to include our custom app settings.

The site comes up fine, logging in using both AD and our custom FBA membership provider works as well.

Certain pages are visible in the Site Libraries through View All Site Content and using SharePoint Designer but SharePoint says that the page(s) are not found if you try to view them or check them in. Not all pages are not available. If I delete a bad page and replace it with a copy from our production application, it displays fine.

I've already found and tried possible solutions such as restarting the Search Query and Site Settings Service and checking the Alternate Access Mapping. I also found a possible solution that has you go to Component Services and modify security relative to an OSearch14 property. I was not able to modify this since right clicking on the property did not pop up any menu options. I will continue to look into this.

Any Ideas? I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: I was able to modify the Component Services OSearch14 property by launching dcomcnfg.exe from a command prompt using "Run as Administrator" but the pages still will not display (SharePoint thinks they do not exist).

Comment: I decided to look in the ULS logs for more information. I should have looked there first since we use MetaLogic StoragePoint in our production environment which uses FileStreaming and this seems to be the issue. In our test environments, we do not have this solution loaded so SharePoint is looking for these missing pages in a remote File Streaming location that is not setup. I will provide a final update to this question once I speak to the person that is responsible for MetaLogic.